# "Color" attribute does not work on <mat-toolbar> in a side navigation in Angular Materia

Tags: angular, angular-material

I cannot make the `mat-toolbar` to change color according to my theme. Please see my code:

**HTML**

```
<mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" >Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Health Check" color="primary">poll</mat-icon>
        &nbsp; Poll
      </a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Health Check" color="primary">info</mat-icon>
          &nbsp; Announcements
      </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
```

But in the content, I don't get any issues. Please see my code.

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

        <a mat-button href="#">
          <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Health Check">accessibility_new</mat-icon>
          Health Check
        </a>
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <div *ngIf="!isXs">
          <a mat-button href="#">
            <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Health Check">poll</mat-icon>
            Poll
          </a>
          <a mat-button href="#">
            <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Health Check">info</mat-icon>
            Announcements
          </a>
        </div>

    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

This is the image:
[image]

Comment: Can you add it to stackblitz

Comment: Add stackblitz as you can see this example works perfectly. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-toolbar-color?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar.component.ts

Comment: @MrKhan, Sir, I have no problem if it is the toolbar in the header. The <mat-toolbar> that is in the <mat-sidenav> component. I don't know how to place it in stackblitz. sorry...

Answer (score 1):

In the mat-nav component need to change css from:

```
.sidenav .mat-toolbar {
  background: inherit;
}
```

to

```
.sidenav {
  background: inherit;
}
```

This problem arise when mat-nav component is created by schematics.